# behavior of AND operation while using with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, logical-operators, short-circuiting

I have a question about behavior of AND operation while using with XPath. Currently it evaluates each and every condition while searching in the XPath even though the first condition itself fails. This is weird. Isn't it?

There are loads of languages that follow the short circuit behavior while evaluating the logical AND operation.

Why is Xpath so different? OR is there any other way or configurations to tell XPath to behave like any other language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 here.

XPath 1.0 (quoted by @wero) says that the conditions MUST be evaluated in order, and evaluation MUST stop as soon as a condition returns false.

XPath 2.0 is much more liberal, and allows the conditions to be evaluated in any order or in parallel.

Why is XPath 2.0 different? Because it's following the tradition of declarative database query languages rather than the tradition of procedural programming languages. In database query languages, re-arranging boolean expressions to make maximum use of indexes is a critical optimization strategy, that can make a difference between a query running in milliseconds and taking hours. Since expressions can't have side-effects in a declarative language, mandating order of execution is really counter-productive.

When you say  "it evaluates each and every condition" your pronoun "it" is not referring to XPath the language, it is referring to a specific XPath implementation. It would be interesting to know (a) which one, and (b) how you observed this behaviour and came to these conclusions.

Comment: Well said Michael, XPath 2.0 prefers optimization over the order of evaluation.

Comment: Is there any way or any configuration with which we can tell XPath to evaluate the conditions in the order and the stop as soon as any of the condition returns false?

Comment: In XPath 2.0 to force this you have to write `if (A) then B else false()`. (Even then, the spec guarantees that evaluation of B doesn't cause an error if it fails, it doesn't actually guarantee that B isn't evaluated, so if A and B are calls to external functions with side-effects, you still get no absolute guarantee.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bug in your xpath engine. Take a look at the [XPath recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans):

> An and expression is evaluated by evaluating each operand and
>   converting its value to a boolean as if by a call to the boolean
>   function. The result is true if both values are true and false
>   otherwise. The right operand is **not evaluated** if the left operand
>   evaluates to false.